# Flutter: Trying to open app from firebase push via background message handler

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to open app or a widget from background message handler of Firebase push.
Currently facing the following error while trying to navigate or call a widget:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
```

Any kind of suggestion would be highly appreciated. :)

Implemented Code:

```
Future initialise() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    }

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        handleNotification(message, false,"onMessage");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        handleNotification(message, true,"onLaunch");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        handleNotification(message, true,"onResume");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    );

    String token = await _fcm.getToken();
    print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");
}

static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('myBackgroundMessageHandler : $message');
    Navigator.of(NavigationService.navigationKey.currentContext).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginCheck()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

    return Future<void>.value();
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Taba not yet... :(